# Recording vlc stream from android device

Tags: android, streaming, vlc, recording

I want to develop an application in android which can record the VLC Stream(http or rtsp).

I am running VLC Player on my Fedora 16(32 bit) system, and I will start streaming using VLC HTTP Streaming option. I am able to get the stream and play it in android device (Sony Experia Neo L ICS 4.0.4) with MediaPlayer class properly. But I don't want to play, just I want to record the same in android device.

How I need to do?

Help me to solve this.

Thank You

Rajendra

Comment: i have tried with url and url connection class...this is not working so i am asking what is the way to start to achieve this task